# MediaStream camera and mic labels before permission given?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webrtc, webcam-capture, mediastream

It's trivial to get this kind of [code](https://github.com/stereostream/stereostream-angular/blob/master/src/app/webrtc/webrtc.component.ts) to work:

```
const videoTracks = this.localStream.getVideoTracks();
const audioTracks = this.localStream.getAudioTracks();
if (videoTracks.length > 0)
  this.trace('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
if (audioTracks.length > 0)
  this.trace('Using audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
```

How about before the devices are chosen?

```
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .enumerateDevices()
    .then(this.gotDevices.bind(this))
    .catch(this.alertsService.add.bind(this.alertsService));
}

gotDevices(deviceInfos: MediaDeviceInfo[]) {
    this.mediaDeviceInfos = deviceInfos;
    this.mediaDeviceInfos.forEach(device => {
        if (device.kind === 'audioinput')
          this.mics.push(device);
        else if (device.kind === 'videoinput')
          this.cams.push(device);
        else
          console.warn(`Unexpected: ${JSON.stringify(device)}`);
    });
}
```

`this.mediaDeviceInfos.some(dev => dev.label)` is `false`. So I have to use `dev.deviceId` in my input, which is ugly:

[image: camera choice screen]

I need the specific device chosen here because I use it like so, to support multiple cams and mics:

```
const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
  audio: { advanced: [{ deviceId: mic.deviceId, groupId: mic.groupId }] },
  video: { advanced: [{ deviceId: cam.deviceId, groupId: cam.groupId }] }
};
```

**How do I get labels for my camera and mic, so they user can choose them in theme?**

Comment: Do you not get the object having a `"label"` property at `this.mediaDeviceInfos = deviceInfos;`?

Comment: Yes, but label is always `""` on Firefox 57.0b6 & 57.0b7 (64-bit). Hang on, just checked Chrome and it works there. Hmm…

Comment: Confirmed `""` label on Firefox 56.0.1 (64-bit) also

Answer (score 2):

You can call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` within `.then()` chained to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`. When protocol is `https:` and permission is granted to the device or devices the `MediaDeviceInfo` object `"label"` property should be set to the available media device.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(/* {video:true, audio:true} */)
.then(stream => 
    navigator.mediaDevices
    .enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
      return devices
    })
    .catch(err => {throw err})
)
.then(devices => {
  console.log(devices);
  for (const mediaDeviceInfo of devices) {
    const {deviceId, kind, label} = mediaDeviceInfo;
      console.log(deviceId, kind, label);
  }
})
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't request (yet) the https protocol, but yes, for security measure (to avoid fingerprinting) you need to be granted user's permission before being able to get the `label` and indeed requesting it through gUM is required (btw, your function could close the gUM request after you got access to the labels, I wrote this while I still not understood your answer which almost does the same: https://jsfiddle.net/cg2110zj/

Comment: @guest271314 and @Kaiido: Thanks but that won't work, [`getUserMedia` has `advanced` options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a6555921f4b1d51281b1241c69e91e5b82d2f07e/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L283) allowing specification of `groupId`, `deviceId` &etc. instead of simply a `boolean`. Because the user is adding two+ cameras and mics, it makes sense to show them in the rendered view rather than the browser-native give-permissions popup. So I take it to be possible on Chrome and not Firefox then? :\

Comment: @SamuelMarks You can use `deviceId` in FF too, you can even access the list of all devices available. What you can't do, is to get their `label` (i.e the manufacturer name), and this to avoid random website to identify you through this personal information. To get this info, in FF you need to be granted user's approval to use at least one of these devices. So, if you really want to display these labels, you can do a first request, only intended to get access to the devices labels. https://jsfiddle.net/cg2110zj/1/ Or you could always use generic names: https://jsfiddle.net/cg2110zj/2/

Comment: Chrome has the same strict policy of not showing the device labels before the user allows access. But it persists the permission much more aggressively which may make it look like it behaves different.

Comment: @PhilippHancke good point. Do you know if there has been discussion in the working group about a way for us web-devs to request user permissions even without doing a gUM request per se (could be useful e.g for this exact case)

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#privacy-and-security-considerations covers that topic. It seems unlikely that this is going to change but feel free to raise an issue here: https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main